# Why Haskell is giving a parse error for this code?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make a program that reads a number given by a user and then prints it. the number has to be an integer when I print it, but this code gives me a parse error:

```
main = do
{
       putStrLn "Please enter the number"
       number <- getLine
       putStrLn "The num is:" ++ show (read number:: Int)
}
```

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: 3:8: Parse error in pattern: putStrLn

Comment: That was my first question too, but you can easily guess just by looking at the code, so it's okay :)

Answer (score 10):

If you use brackets in your `do` statement, you have to use semicolons. Also, the last line should be `putStrLn $ "The num is:" ++ show (read number :: Int)`

So you have two options:

```
main = do
{
   putStrLn "Please enter the number";
   number <- getLine;
   putStrLn $ "The num is:" ++ show (read number:: Int)
}
```

or:

```
main = do
   putStrLn "Please enter the number"
   number <- getLine
   putStrLn $ "The num is:" ++ show (read number:: Int)
```

Almost all of the code I've seen uses the second version, but they are both valid. Note that in the second version, whitespace becomes significant.

Comment: can you please tell me how i can read this number as integer directly or how to convert it afterwards

Comment: You can just use `readLn :: IO Int` instead of `getLine`. In this snippet, there is not enough information to infer it's a number without specifying it somewhere; if you actually did some numeric stuff with it, you'd be able to use `readLn` by itself.

Comment: suppose the user inputs 10 and then compiler should ask user to input 10 numbers and then form a list. how can that be done using sequence?

Comment: I think you're best off asking something unrelated like that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell recognizes the Tab character and your program could be failing because of that. If you're using Tabs, change them to whitespaces.

Comment: That does often cause trouble, but it wasn't the problem here.